# Changing a line's length in Visio without affecting its angle

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2016

Is there a way to lock the angles of lines?
I would like to be able to set a line’s angle and then resize it by grabbing one end and dragging it around, without concern of changing the line’s angle.

[image: Example]

The "Rotation" box here appears to not be relevant.

[image: Protection]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to lock the rotation of a two-dimensional object, but not
of one-dimensional object which is the line.

You would be better off by changing the line's length via the
Size & Position window, rather than by dragging the end-point.

Comment: That’s a shame. There are many times when you’re slightly off grid and try to   pull a 0 degree line (for example) over to some other object, and have it end up as -0.02 degrees - or some such nonsense. So aggravating.